Show that there are exactly $t$ maximal ideals of $\mathbb Q_{(p)}$.
First of all, this is the same question in that link. Let $ t \in \mathbb{N} $ and let $ p_1, p_2, \dots, p_t $ be $ t $ distinct prime numbers. Show that
$$R = \left\{\dfrac{m}{n} :m\in \mathbb Z,n\in \mathbb N\text{ such that } n \text{ is not divisible by } p_1, p_2, \dots, p_t \right\}$$
has exactly $ t $ maximal ideals.
It is clear that $Q_{(i)} := \left\{\dfrac{m}{n} \text{ for some } m\in \mathbb Z,n\in \mathbb N \text{ s.t } n \text{ is not divisible by of } p_1, \dots, p_t \text{ and } p_i | m \right\} \triangleleft R.$
Hence, $R$ has $t$ maximal ideals as $Q_1,\dots,Q_t$ which are ideals of $R$ which are $t$ of them. My question is why they are exactly $t$ of them?
According to hint, consider $I' := I \cap \mathbb{Z}$ where $I$ is maximal ideal of $R$. $I'$ is an ideal of $\mathbb Z$ which must be of the form $ a\mathbb{Z}$ where $ a$ is multiple of $p_i$. That is, we have $p_i\mathbb{Z} \triangleleft \mathbb{Z}$, which is prime. Moreover, $I'$ has to be one of the ideals $p_i\mathbb{Z}, \, i = 1, 2, \dots, t.$

I think that you intended the reverse divisibility relations in your definition of $Q_{(t+1)}$. Like $p_1,\ldots,p_t\nmid n$.

But it's not clear to me whether you want your want your approach dissected/criticized or the a solution to the question. I'm not sure you have worked enough on this for me to want to post a solution. But I want to help you give you get started on showing real work with the following hint. If $I$ is an arbitrary ideal of $R$, what can you say about the intersection $I':=I\cap \Bbb{Z}$. 1) Remember that ideals of $\Bbb{Z}$ are all principal. 2) Why does maximality of $I$ imply that $I'$ is a prime ideal? Go from there!

$I' := I \cap \mathbb{Z}$ will be an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$, which must be of the form $a\mathbb{Z}$ where $a$ is a multiple of $p_i$, as $I$ is a maximal ideal, which is one of the form $Q_{(i)}$. So, indeed, we have $p_i \mathbb{Z} \triangleleft \mathbb{Z}$, which is prime.

Correct. $I'$ has to be one of the ideal $p_i\Bbb{Z}$, $i=1,2,\ldots,t$. Do you see why? Do you see why it settles the question? Please add some of the progress to the question body (or post as an answer, if you think you solved your question).

Dear @JyrkiLahtonen, I couldn't see why this finishes the proof. Could you give me a hand?

Extending the hints from the comments to an answer. Justify the following claims. Ask for alternatives, if some step is too difficult.

Let $I\subset R$ be a maximal ideal. Then $I':=I\cap \Bbb{Z}$ is an ideal of $\Bbb{Z}$. So $I'=a\Bbb{Z}$ for some integer $a$.
The mapping $n\mapsto n+I$ is a ring homomorphism from $\Bbb{Z}$ to the quotient ring $R/I$. Its kernel is equal to $I'$. Therefore $\Bbb{Z}_a\simeq\Bbb{Z}/I'$ is isomorphic to a subring of $R/I$.
Because $I$ is a maximal ideal $R/I$ is a field. Together with the previous bullet this implies that $a$ must be a prime number, say $a=p$.
So $a/1=p/1$ is an element of $I$. If $p$ is not one of the primes $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_t$, show that $p/1$ is a unit of $R$. Why is this a contradiction?
So there exists an index $i$, $1\le i\le t$, such that $p=p_i$. Why is it impossible for the ideal $I$ to contain the element $p_j/1$, $j\neq i$?
Conclude.


Steps 2 and 3 can be combined if you are familiar with the concept of a prime ideal.
